# Is there anyway to find packages installed into Sitecore instance

Tags: installation

In Sitecore, there is a facility to install Sitecore packages.

Is there a way to view what packages are installed into our Sitecore instance and when they got installed ?

Are there any modules to support this functionality ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no user interface that would show you the package installation history out of the box, but seeing it is pretty easy. Sitecore stores information about installed packages in the Core databases under the following path:

`/sitecore/system/packages/installation history`

If you want to know more details about this, read the following blog post:

http://kirkegaard-at.blogspot.bg/2013/10/sitecore-package-installation-history.html

There's also a Sitecore module on the marketplace that provides a UI for package installation history:

https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/PackageHistory.aspx

Comment: Note that this will only show you packages installed via the installer. If you are trying to see which modules are installed, they may have been installed in other ways (deployment, publishing, etc.) on a particular instance.

Comment: @JasonSt-Cyr - how would you check for packages/modules NOT installed via the installer? :0

Comment: It ain't easy, I'll tell ya :) When I had to do so back in the day, I looked for specific items or files that would indicate the presence of a module. If they existed in the database and on the file system, I could make an assumption that it was installed. However, it's only an indication. If one item out of 300 is installed, and that 1 item is the one I check for? Now I have a false positive.